# C# runtime introspection on Tuple

Tags: c#, reflection, tuples

In my C# application, I need to display a Tuple to users. The problem is that the Tuple could be of any form, and I don't know at compile time what the Tuple will look like, so I have to introspect on it at runtime to display it. The first problem is to identify the type of each component in the tuple, and the second is to get the value of each component.

Getting the value of each component seems to involve Item1, Item2, and so on, but is there a way to get at Items by index? Currently my code is really clunky because I have to use the number of components to decide how may items to iterate through (see below). The bigger problem is however, how to get at the elements because I don't know how to get the Tuple object. The following code compiles, but at runtime the cast of the object to Tuple throws an error of this form:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Tuple`2[System.String,System.Byte[]]' to type 'System.Tuple`2[System.Object,System.Object]'.

It looks like the cast fails (I think I understand why), but I don't know how to rewrite the cast to get around this. I have tried things like:

```
object rowObject = ((Tuple<tupleTypeArray[0], tupleTypeArray[1]>)tupleObject ).Item1;
```

but this does not compile. Help would be appreciated!

```
tupleObject = SomeTupleGotFromMethodCall();
Type tupleType = tupleObject.GetType();
Type[] tupleTypeArray = tupleType.GenericTypeArguments;
int tupleLength = tupleType.GenericTypeArguments.Count<Type>();
for (int i = 0; i < tupleLength; i++)
{
    if (tupleLength == 1)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            Type firstType = tupleTypeArray[0];
            object rowObject = ((Tuple<object>)tupleObject).Item1;
            if (rowObject != null)
            {
                display(rowObject);
            }
        }
    }

    if (tupleLength == 2)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            object rowObject = ((Tuple<object, object>)tupleObject).Item1;
            if (rowObject != null)
            {
                display(rowObject);
            }
        }

        if (i == 1)
        {
            object rowObject = ((Tuple<object, object>)tupleObject).Item2;
            display(rowObject);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: using tuple as a list is like never a good idea, do you have the implementation of your method that return the tuples ?

Comment: No - I don't have any control over what comes back - this is a separate library. Tuples are not the only type of object that could come back (and I handle these other types) before getting to the code above.

Comment: i would say first of all 'object' is a type so your first two lines make no sense (and avery cast after that)

Comment: Yes, sorry - I edited the code for readability, but used a bad variable name! I have updated the question to correct that.

Comment: could not you use something like
var item1 = tupleObject.GetType().GetProperty("Item1").GetValue(tupleobject, null); and so on ?

Comment: Thanks - yes, your last comment works. I'm also going to look at the answer below which looks interesting.

Answer (score 1):

This can't work:

```
object rowObject = ((Tuple<object>)tupleObject).Item1;
```

Because `Tuple<int>` *is not* `Tuple<object>`. Just because `int` inherits from `object` doesn't mean that `Tuple<int>` inherits from `Tuple<object>`.

What you really want to do is get all the properties of an object of unknown type, and display them. This isn't a tuple problem, particularly. There's nothing about doing this with a tuple that differs from doing it with any other object. Properties are properties. Unless they're fields; then they're not properties at all. But with tuples, they're properties.

So we'll just write a quick extension method that returns all the names and values of the public properties of any given object -- and we'll throw in the types of the properties too, because we may as well be complete.

Once you've got the names and values of the properties, you can write code to display them any way you like.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    //  nuget Install-Package "System.ValueTuple" if the compiler gives you any backtalk
    public static List<(String Name, Type Type, Object Value)> 
        GetPublicPropertiesWithValues(this object obj)
    {
        return 
            obj.GetType()
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Select(p => (
                Name: p.Name, 
                Type: p.PropertyType, 
                Value: p.GetValue(obj)
            ))
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tuple = new Tuple<String, Object, double, float, Tuple<String, String>>(
            "foo", "bar", 34.56, 5.43f, new Tuple<string, string>("Fred", "Barney"));

        tuple.GetPublicPropertiesWithValues().ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
(Item1, System.String, foo)
(Item2, System.Object, bar)
(Item3, System.Double, 34.56)
(Item4, System.Single, 5.43)
(Item5, System.Tuple`2[System.String,System.String], (Fred, Barney))
```